# Take or catch particular number of bus?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I have this sentence:

> Take the number seven bus to London.

Can we say

> **Catch** the number seven bus to London.

Which should be used in BrE and which in AmE?

I think we can't 'catch the number seven bus to London' because of it is like 'to take route' and we can't catch 'route'. but I'm not sure about it.

Comment: Don't you mean particular?

Comment: I mean a particular bus - number seven bus.

Comment: There is no difference in [catch vs. take](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/53764) usage simply because you designate a specific bus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Catch* instead of *Take* would be less likely here because there is no time factor involved; if you're trying to get to London by some particular deadline, you might want to "catch the 3:00 bus" in order to get there by 4:00.  (In other words, in order to use *catch*, there should be some possibility to *miss* as well.)

You could also speak of "catching the first (or the next) bus" since you are referring to one particular bus, as opposed to any bus traveling the given route.

However, this is a minor distinction, and if you do use *catch* it will be perfectly understandable.

Comment: In California AmE I usually hear "take" for a bus, not catch, again because the schedules are pretty much fixed. But it is more common to hear "catch a flight", since as we all know flight schedules are not so fixed. This might especially apply when someone will try to "catch" an earlier flight. As Hellion points out, certainty of the timing is the main factor.

Answer (score 0):

Both are fine. And I don't know if there is any BrE and AmE difference based on this. Most likely they are equally possible in both English. I am leaving this conclusion to native speakers. Native speakers, please help here.

Answer (score 0):

I have a slightly different take on this.  Catch and take are interchangeable, both in AmE and BrE (I have caught and taken quite a few buses both in the US and in the UK).

On the other hand, there is a different "flavor" to the two words, as the other answerers are saying.  Hellion puts the difference very well: if there's some chance of missing your bus, then catch is the verb used; if not, then take.

The reason that take and catch are interchangeable is because, as I'm sure Hellion will agree, there is *always* a chance to miss the bus.  You can be standing there 15 minutes early, have the bus show up, have one person get off, and have the driver let the person in front of you on and then say "sorry, all full, catch the next one."

Catch conveys the meaning of buses always attempting to leave one behind (which as everyone knows they are) and therefore having be caught to be used.  Take is more matter-of-fact; it simply means using the bus as the means of travel.  So, as I see it, the question of whether you use catch or take is simply a question of whether or not you want to convey a sense of identification with the stress shared by bus travellers the world over who are depending on a bus as their means of transportation.

Comment: Catch and take _are_ almost interchangeable. I would use _take_ more to emphasize that I am riding on the bus to my destination, while _catch_ would be act of trying to meet up with the bus at the right time and place and actually getting on it. A little less drama and time pressure indicated in _take_ than in _catch_.

Comment: I haven't said they aren't, as a perusal of my answer will reveal, no?  I don't disagree with your statement.  I'm saying that they are (almost) interchangeable because of the simple fact that taking a bus always involves catching it in some way.

Comment: I'm just saying that I don't consider them _exactly_ interchangeable, that _catch_ is a little more "dramatic" and _take_ is a little more mundane.

Comment: Yes, me too!  :)